# Why can't I run a static void method from the global scope?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a class where I want to call a static method to initialize some things. I tried calling it from the global scope, like in this simplified example:

```
class MyClass{
  static bool initialized = false;
  
  static void init(){
    initialized = true;
  }
}

MyClass.init();


void main() async {  
  // Do something useful
}
```

This results in the following errors:

- Functions must have an explicit list of parameters
- The name 'MyClass' is already defined

What I find a bit odd is that if I make the `init()` method return something and assign that result to a variable, it works:

```
class MyClass{
  static bool initialized = false;
  
  static bool init(){
    initialized = true;
    return true;
  }
}

bool _dummy = MyClass.init();



void main() async {  
  // Do something useful
}
```

Why is this? And is there a better workaround to call a static **void** method from the global scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that static variables are lazy evaluated in Dart, so they will first get a value the first time they are accessed.

That means that `MyClass.init()` in:

```
bool _dummy = MyClass.init();
```

Is only being executed when something are trying to access the variable `_dummy`. It also means that the following in global scope:

```
MyClass.init();
```

Does not make any sense in Dart since this code are never going to be executed since there are no reference to the code.

The reason for this design can be found described in the Dart Language Specification:

> Static variable declarations with an initializing expression are initialized lazily.
>
> *The lazy semantics are given because we do not want a language where one tends to define expensive initialization computations, causing long application startup times. This is especially crucial for Dart, which must support the coding of client applications.*

https://dart.dev/guides/language/specifications/DartLangSpec-v2.10.pdf